# Simulate an evaluator

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm simulating an evaluator with Haskell. It should be simple but I couldn't debug.

Here I define `State` as a look-up function (`String -> Int`), an initial state (`empty`, exception variable evaluates `0`), and `extend` to add new key (and it's value) to a `base` environment:

```
type State = String -> Int

extend :: State -> String -> Int -> State
extend base key val = \x -> if key == x
                                 then val
                                 else base key

empty :: State
empty = \x -> 0
```

when I test the program:

```
aState = extend empty  "A" 5
bState = extend aState "B" 4
cState = extend bState "C" 3
```

I suppose that `cState` should be equivalent to a function:

```
\x -> if x == "C"
          then 3
          else if x == "B"
                   then 4
                   else if x == "A"
                            then 5
                            else 0
```

But instead, I get `cState "B" == 0` and `cState "A" == 0`.

I can't see what is wrong with `extend`, could somebody explain to me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `else` statement, you search `key` (rather than `x`) in every recursion: `else base key`. Fix it with:

```
extend :: State -> String -> Int -> State
extend base key val = \x -> if key == x
                                 then val
                                 else base x
```

---

BTW, you might write:

```
empty :: State
empty = \_ -> 0
```

since `empty` return `0` regardless of input.